# What did the letter really say?

Tags: fairy-tail

In episode 25 of the new fairy tail season *spoilers, doh*

> UL sends Jellal and Meldy a letter.[image]

What did the message actually say? My eye sight is to bad to properly read it, but I had the feeling the translation was off.

Comment: "as well as finally trusting that a day will come when you can be forgiven. I means never hiding yourself from love, your true battle is still ahead of you... If we can not defeat Zeref. Wizard kind will again be awash in grief. please live on for me... ...and battle on, this journey of your... will bring happiness to all. That is what I pray" this is how I read it, not sure about some word...

Comment: Damn the handwriting is even worse than that of mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As well as finally trusting that a day
>
> will come when you can be forgiven.
>
> It means never hiding yourself from love.
>
> Your true battle is still aheard<sup>sic</sup> of you...
>
> If we can not defeat Zeref,
>
> wizardkind will again be awash in grief.
>
> Please live on, for me...
>
> ...and battle on, this journey of your<sup>sic</sup>...
>
> will bring happiness to all.
>
> That is what I pray.

It is not proper English. "aheard" is not a word, and "your" should be "yours".